# Tstrut and Bstrut seem to be messing up the centering of my table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I'd like to have some spacing between the hlines of my table, but Bstrut and Tstrut (which I understand are the standard ways of dealing with this issue) are adding unwanted empty characters that are messing up my centering in the table

Here's my code for it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\Tstrut{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}}         % = `top' strut
\newcommand\Bstrut{\rule[-0.9ex]{0pt}{0pt}}   % = `bottom' strut


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| c c c | c |}
\hline
$ \alpha $ & $ \beta $ & $ \gamma $ & $ \#(\alpha,\beta,\gamma) $ \Tstrut\Bstrut\\
\hline
T & T & T & T \Tstrut\\
T & T & F & T \\
T & F & T & T \\
T & F & F & F \\
F & T & T & T \\
F & T & F & F \\
F & F & T & F \\
F & F & F & F \Bstrut\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should omit the space in `T \Tstrut` (and `F \Bstrut`), because now TeX centers the whole expression: T, horizontal space, box of width 0. Its width is larger than width of `T`, hence the shift visible in your table.